# Installing Tenserflow on GPU NVIDIA GeForce MX230

Tags: python, gpu, nvidia

Is it worth installing Tenserflow on a **NVIDIA GeForce MX230** (It is CUDA Supported ). https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/gaming-laptops/geforce-mx230/specifications/ or should I just install it on a **intel i5 10th gen CPU**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow is going to perform better with GPU, but MX230 isn't that powerful. I also have MX230, but I instead use google colab.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it for Testing/Learning purpose then use "Google Colab" or "Kaggle Notebook" they are the best.

But if you want to work on some project/office work then install it on a Local computer.